# What is the transmission bandwidth for a BASK (Binary Amplitude Shift Keying) signal?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-modulation

What is the transmission bandwidth for  a BASK (Binary Amplitude Shift Keying) signal?
Shouldn't it be infinity as short periods of sinusoids are used to depict 1 and 0 to depict 0?

Comment: If the bandwidth were infinite, you couldn't transmit it.  Heck, you couldn't even generate it.

Comment: @ Dave Tweed I believe you can read my answer as addressing the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bandwidth is defined by the pulse shape, not the modulation type.

So, this depends on

1. how you define bandwidth (there's different definitions, and which one you use depends on the purpose of defining the bandwidth)
2. which transmit pulse shaping filter you use.

Comment: Yeah, read one of the definitions, which  stated that the BW be taken as the width of main (central) lobe in the frequency spectrum(on the +ve frequencies).